# Flash CS5 Android and Blackberry Development

Tags: android, flash, blackberry, air

If I build a Android and Blackberry app with Flash/AIR, do i get access to the file system and database for both platforms?

My app will need to save downloaded images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you have access to the [applicationStorageDirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory) (etc.) from [flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) for both Android OS and BlackBerry Tablet OS platforms.

BlackBerry Tablet OS:  [Application sandbox file system layout](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Application-sandbox-file-system-layout/td-p/732177)

Android + useful reading:  [Working with File objects in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html)

Comment: Thanks a heap. I appreciate the answer